# Using variable returned by AJAX in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Within the HTML tag on my `addtodb.php` file, I have a button that only shows up if a user is logged in:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_SESSION["userid"])){
        echo "<button onclick='hiya()'> Add Image to User </button>";       
    }
?>
```

Right below that, I have the following script:

```
<script>
        function itsucceeded(){
            console.log("great");
            document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<?php echo 'a change hast occured';?>");
        }

        function hiya(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "wattapain.php",           //page containing php you want to run
                type: "POST",               //request type
                data : {clicked: "john"},   //data to be sent to the server
                success: itsucceeded()      //function to be called if the request succeeds
            })
        }
</script>
```

`wattapain.php` includes only the following code:

```
<?php
     $clicked = $_POST['clicked'];
     echo "HI".$clicked;
?>
```

The console.log and the insertAdjacentHTML calls work, but no matter what I put in the PHP, it doesn't run. At first, the PHP stuff was in the same file (addtodb.php) but that wasn't working, and all the examples online were using separate php files anyway, so I created wattapain.php and even stopped checking if `isset($_POST["clicked"])` but nothing is working. I can't tell what's wrong and would really appreciate your help.

And please please please don't close this question insisting that a post from 5 years ago answers my question. Trust me, it doesn't, I've been at this for two hours already and an hour and a half of that has been spent on Stack Overflow reading similar questions and not being able to fix this bug.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if this is really doable, on page load the php code gets executed server side and the resulting html is returned and served to the browser as html. You cant inject php after the fact into an environment that doesnt execute php. Look into setting id's & classes onto your dom elements and updating the dom via api calls like document.getElementById & getElemensByClass

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs in web browser, while PHP runs on backend server. `<?php echo 'a change hast occured';?>`  can't be recognized by the browser. You can modify `itsucceeded` to get reponse text of wattapain.php.

```
  <script>
    function itsucceeded(resp){
        console.log("great");
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", resp.responseText);
    }

    function hiya(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "wattapain.php",           //page containing php you want to run
            type: "POST",               //request type
            data : {clicked: "john"},   //data to be sent to the server
            success: itsucceeded      //function to be called if the request succeeds
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How do I get the response text of a PHP file?

Comment: Actually, if that PHP code is inside a .PHP file, that line would be seen by the browser as `            document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "a change hast occured");`

Comment: @CodingMee I have updated my answer, you can try the code. the response text of wattapain.php should be "HIjohn".

Comment: @emptyhua I can't tell what you changed.